# CDCLVC1104 output logic status

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, texas-instruments

I have used [CDCLVC1104](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cdclvc1104.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1626681943684&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.digikey.in%252F) in my design. There is a table on page 10 of the data-sheet showing the output logic states with respect to "CLKIN" and "1G"(Enable).

[image]

I have encountered another state which is not defined in this table.

"CLKIN" is left floating and the "1G"(Enable) is connected to high voltage. what will be the output logic in this state?

There is no mention of this state in the data-sheet.

Can someone share some information on this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

With CMOS logic, action with floating inputs is undefined.  CMOS inputs are very high impedance, so an unconnected input may take any value, and may change randomly, so the outputs also will change randomly, and may output invalid logic levels.

Answer (score 1):

> "CLKIN" is left floating and the "1G"(Enable) is connected to high voltage. what will be the output logic in this state?
>
> There is no mention of this state in the data-sheet.

The data sheet won't mention that state, because it's not a 'state', it's a design error. The clock should never be left floating. Not in a CDCLVC1104, not in **any** CMOS logic. The output in this state is **UNDEFINED**. It might be 1, it might be 0, it could be random or oscillating, it might even be smoke.

Comment: What if I provide pull down/pull up option at the input? In the absence of the "CLKIN", still the output will be "Undefined"??

Comment: The pull-up/pull-down would define if the node is high or low if nothing else is driving it.

Comment: @Justme So it would avoid the input from floating right?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 That's what pull-ups and pull-downs do.

Comment: @MightyBeard007 If you provide a pullup or -down, then the input isn't floating, it's pulled by the pullx resistor to a clean 0 or 1.